# Palindrome Algorithm and UnboundLocalError

Tags: python, algorithm, palindrome

This is my code to find the longest palindrome within a String.
I get the following error message:
"UnboundLocalError: local variable 'Current_Pal' referenced before assignment"

I know that the variable 'Current_Pal" should be within the isPal function but if I do this the variable will be initialized to zero at every loop.

```
def isPalindrome(s):
    Current_Pal = ''
    Longest_Pal = ''

    def toChars(s):
       s = s.lower()
       ans= ''
       for c in s:
           if c in 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz':
                ans = ans+ c
       return ans

    def isPal(s):
        if len(s) <= 1:
             return Current_Pal + s
        else:
            if s[0] == s[-1]:
                Current_Pal = Current_Pal + s[0]

        else:
            if Current_Pal > Longest_Pal:
                Longest_Pal = Current_Pal
                Current_Pal = ''
        return isPal(s[1:-1])
return isPal(toChars(s))

Palin = isPalindrome("HYTBCABADEFGHABCDEDCBAGHTFYW1234567887654321ZWETYGDE")
print(Palin)
```

Comment: Pass in the value of `Current_Pal` as a parameter in each call to `isPal()`.

Comment: Understood, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a recursive function so you need to pass in an initial `Current_Pal` and keep passing that variable to the subsequent calls; you can also do the same for `Longest_Pal`, like below:

```
def isPal(s, Current_Pal='', Longest_Pal=''):
    if len(s) <= 1:
         return Current_Pal + s
    else:
        if s[0] == s[-1]:
            Current_Pal = Current_Pal + s[0]

    else:
        if Current_Pal > Longest_Pal:
            Longest_Pal = Current_Pal
            Current_Pal = ''
    return isPal(s[1:-1], Current_Pal, Longest_Pal)
```

This way it's set to `''` and then the additional changes are continually passed into the method, retaining its previous value.

On a side note, you should probably rewrite your else statements:

```
def isPal(s, Current_Pal='', Longest_Pal=''):
    if len(s) <= 1:
         return Current_Pal + s
    elif s[0] == s[-1]:
            Current_Pal = Current_Pal + s[0]
    elif Current_Pal > Longest_Pal:
            Longest_Pal = Current_Pal
            Current_Pal = ''
    return isPal(s[1:-1], Current_Pal, Longest_Pal)
```